# A tale of two viewports - width:100% but not full width

Tags: html, css, viewport

I am reading [A tale of two viewport](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) and I could not follow the explanation at **Consequences**. He claims that when one zooms into his page, the upper right corner is not blue anymore even though it has width:100%.

[image]

I do not understand why this should be the case. In fact, I cannot even reproduce it:
[image]

Could someone explain me on a more simple example what the author's point is?

Comment: I can reproduce it. The author's point to is to zoom in so that you get a horizontal scrollbar, then scroll to the right. http://i.stack.imgur.com/L84jy.jpg But you don't have a horizontal scrollbar in your sceenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the effect by using "browser zoom" (not pinch zoom), i.e. ctrl+/-. You need horizontal scrolling to see the effect in the author's example.

When you hit ctrl+ a few times, you're increasing the size of a CSS pixel. This means fewer CSS pixels will fit into your browser window (viewport) and thus zooming in shrinks your viewport. For example, say your viewport is initially 800px wide. You zoom in to 200%. Since each CSS pixel is now double the size, your viewport only fits 400px.

The article's point is that even though the viewport shrunk, the content on the page hasn't (in terms of CSS pixels), it's still ~800px (or whatever the author specified it to) since only the *pixel size* has changed. This means sizes that rely on the viewport will now look disproportional to the rest of the content. In his example, the top bar is set to fill the viewport width 100%. When the content becomes larger than the viewport, the bar will not extend the same width as the content.